# How to write things to USB HID in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, hid, usb-hid

I'm working with a AMOLED screen. The vendor exposes the screen's brightness control to USB HID, and only give me an example webpage that uses Chrome's `navigator.hid`. I read the JavaScript code and find I need to do following things:

- find a USB HID device whose vendor ID is 1810 and product ID is 10;
- at each time I need to set brightness, I have to send a report with report ID of 9 and four bytes of data containing formatted brightness value.

Although it looks really clear and simple, I still don't know how to do these with Linux and C. Especially:

- When I plugged the control USB port, I found there are two new device files: `/dev/hidraw0` and `/dev/usb/hiddev0`. What are difference between them and which one should I use?
- How to do the USB-specific things i.e. fetch vendor ID and product ID, send the report with report ID? Is there a specific header file for `ioctl` flags?

Comment: The new code should be written in eBPF. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

After some study I found the `/dev/hidrawX` device should be used, and the `/dev/usb/hiddevX` is probably for the screen touch input. The API is described in [linux kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/hid/hidraw.html) and no library is needed.

Actually all things are sample and direct. Firstly I should `open` the hidraw device. The vendor ID and product ID can be retrieved using `ioctl` with `HIDIOCGRAWINFO` and struct `hidraw_devinfo`:

```
struct hidraw_devinfo info;
ioctl(fd, HIDIOCGRAWINFO, &info);
```

After identified correct hidraw device, I should write them 5-byte array using `write`. The first byte contains report ID of 9, and the latter four bytes contains the message that make the device happy.